# quickbooks desktop web connector qbxml add job continueOnError not working

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I'm using QuickBooks Enterprise, Web connector ver: 2.1.0.30 and the framework found here: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php.
When adding jobs there are some cases that the same job name exists, so quickbooks gives an error. I want the process to continue after the error so I've set the onError attribute to "continueOnError" as described here: https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/qbsdk/staticHtml/QBD-Attributes.html, but the process stops and the next request (adding an invoice) doesn't execute. I have to re-run for the next request to be processed.
Here is a part of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?qbxml version="2.0"?>
    <QBXML>
          <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
               <CustomerAddRq requestID="...">
                   <CustomerAdd> ...
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Is this the way to go or I need to do something else?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stopOnError` and `continueOnError` flags indicate what to do (stop or continue) with the *remainder of the current request* if an error occurs within the current request.

For example, if you did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?qbxml version="2.0"?>
<QBXML>
      <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
           <CustomerAddRq requestID="1">
           ...
           </CustomerAddRq>
           <InvoiceAddRq requestID="2">
           ...
           </InvoiceAddRq>
       ....
```

You're telling QuickBooks that if an error occurs in the `CustomerAddRq` section, ignore it and continue processing the `InvoiceAddRq` section (vs. if you used `stopOnError` it would not even attempt the `InvoiceAddRq` after encountering an error in the `CustomerAddRq` section.

However, if you're using the Web Connector correctly (you are) then you're sending multiple separate requests, vs. one batched up request like in the example above. Which means that `stopOnError` and `continueOnError` are not what you need.

Instead, what you need is to handle the error in your PHP code with an error handler.

Add a function:

```
/** 
 * Try to handle an error 
 * 
 * @param string $requestID
 * @param string $user         This is the username of the connected Web Connector user
 * @param string $action       The action type that experienced an error (i.e. QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMER, or QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMER, or etc.)
 * @param string $ID           The $ID value of the record that experienced an error (usually your primary key for this record)
 * @param array $extra 
 * @param string $err          If an error occurs **within the error handler**, put an error message here (i.e. if your error handler experienced an internal error), otherwise, leave this NULL
 * @param string $xml
 * @param string $errnum       The error number or error code which occurred
 * @param string $errmsg       The error message received from QuickBooks 
 * @return boolean             Return TRUE if the error was handled and you want to continue processing records, or FALSE otherwise
 */
function my_error_handler($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $xml, $errnum, $errmsg)
{
    // ...
    // return true;     // return TRUE if you want the Web Connector to continue to process requests
    // return false;    // return FALSE if you want the Web Connector to stop processing requests and report the error
}
```

And make sure you tell the QuickBooks PHP lib about your new error handler function:

```
$errmap = array(
    // This is an array mapping the error number/code to the error handler function
    3070 => 'my_error_handler', 

    // You can also use static method error handlers if you don't like functions...
    // 3070 => 'MyStaticClass::myStaticMethod', 

    // ... or object instant error handlers.
    // 3070 => array( $MyObjectInstance, 'myMethod' ), 

    // You can also register a "catch-all" error handler to catch all errors:
    // '*' => 'my_catchall_error_handler', 
    );
```

More info:

- http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_integration_php_consolibyte_webconnector#error_handlers_for_traditional_integrations